# jVectorMaps positioning

Tags: jquery, css, html, jvectormap

I'm working on a simple website with jVectormaps. I have a map of Europe and I would like to position this on the right side of the screen. Height of the map is 100%,so it scales whenever the user resizes their window. But the problem is that my map is centered and I can't figure out a way to position it wherever I want.

Current code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>

    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>

    <script src="jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-jvectormap-world-mill-en.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-jvectormap-europe-mill-en.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map"></div>
    <script>
        $(function (){
            $('#map').vectorMap({
                map: 'europe_mill_en',
                backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                zoomOnScroll: false,
                regionStyle: {
                    initial: {
                        fill: 'red'
                    },
                    hover: {
                        fill: 'yellow'
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

#map {
    height: 100%;
}
```

I tried to use display: block and float: right, but that doesn't seems to work. I can't find any help in the provided documentation on the website.

Any advice?

Thx in advance

Answer (score 0):

This seems like it has more to do with HTML/CSS rather than jVectorMap, but regardless, you could try wrapping your map in another div and aligning the contents of that div to the right:

```
.wrapper {
    text-align: right;
}

<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="map"></div>    
</div>
```